# Omniauth ArgumentError in SessionsController#create wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am following an online tutorial to incorporate facebook omniauth to a sample application before adding it to my ROR application ( http://richonrails.com/articles/facebook-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails and https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw) but I am getting a wrong number of arguments error when I visit the "log into from facebook link".

```
ArgumentError in SessionsController#create wrong number of arguments (1 for 2).
```

Here is my user model (straight from the tutorial) and where the error appears to be coming from, line 3 is highlighted as the source

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
 end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

 def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
 end
```

I don't have the coffee script from the 2nd tutorial in there, I get a different error when I use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm not sure that it resolves your problem, but seems `first_or_initialize` doesn't need `tap` method

Comment: Just for kicks I removed tap and didn't make a difference. I did try playing around with the config files and did eventually get this error {
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}

Comment: I am now trying to figure out if one comes before the other or if they are totally unrelated. The newer error I get from FB rather than Rails.

Comment: And yes I did google the error and made changes to my config files

Answer (score 0):

I down graded the omniauth-facebook gem to '1.4.0' and it worked fine.